# any docker command gives error: bad symbol table

Tags: docker, ubuntu, go

I installed the docker engine successfully and no error or warning is shown.
But after that, whenever I try any docker command, even docker ps, I get this error:

```
runtime: pcdata is -2 and 76 args stack map entries for net/http.(*Transport).dialConn (targetpc=0x55afd17107cb)
fatal error: bad symbol table

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x55afd29a0fb2, 0x10)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:617 +0x74
runtime.getStackMap(0x7f96177fdad0, 0x7f96177fdbd8, 0x55afd1710701, 0x55afd1407b91, 0x0, 0x55afd2a74601, 0x55af00000000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:1274 +0x522
runtime.adjustframe(0x7f96177fdad0, 0x7f96177fdbc0, 0x55afd48c2a20)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:628 +0x86
runtime.gentraceback(0xffffffffffffffff, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0, 0xc0000aa900, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7fffffff, 0x55afd36a4f50, 0x7f96177fdbc0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/traceback.go:341 +0x13a0
runtime.copystack(0xc0000aa900, 0x1000, 0x101)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:881 +0x25d
runtime.newstack()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:1050 +0x301
runtime.morestack()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:429 +0x84

goroutine 25 [copystack]:
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0xc0004f1d40, 0x55afd3729ce0, 0xc0000d4020, 0x0, 0x55afd298d9af, 0x4, 0xc0001323e0, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1150 +0x1fcc fp=0xc000083f00 sp=0xc000083ef8 pc=0x55afd17107cc
net/http.(*Transport).getConn.func4(0xc0004f1d40, 0x55afd3729ce0, 0xc0000d4020, 0xc0004cfec0, 0xc00005c180)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1017 +0xa8 fp=0xc000083fb8 sp=0xc000083f00 pc=0x55afd171a7f8
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337 +0x1 fp=0xc000083fc0 sp=0xc000083fb8 pc=0x55afd1407b91
created by net/http.(*Transport).getConn
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1016 +0x457

goroutine 1 [select]:
net/http.(*Transport).getConn(0xc0004f1d40, 0xc0004cfe90, 0x0, 0x55afd298d9af, 0x4, 0xc0001323e0, 0x17, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1022 +0x63f
net/http.(*Transport).roundTrip(0xc0004f1d40, 0xc0004de700, 0x10, 0xc0003afad0, 0xc000279540)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/transport.go:531 +0x6f1
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc0004f1d40, 0xc0004de700, 0xc0004f1d40, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/roundtrip.go:17 +0x37
net/http.send(0xc0004de700, 0x55afd36d4520, 0xc0004f1d40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0003d0570, 0x55afd15fe788, 0x1, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:250 +0x463
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc0004cfd70, 0xc0004de700, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0003d0570, 0x0, 0x1, 0x55afd33aa540)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:174 +0xfd
net/http.(*Client).do(0xc0004cfd70, 0xc0004de700, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:641 +0x27b
net/http.(*Client).Do(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/client.go:509
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client.(*Client).doRequest(0xc0000e8c00, 0x55afd3729ce0, 0xc0000d4020, 0xc0004de600, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client/request.go:134 +0x13f
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client.(*Client).Ping(0xc0000e8c00, 0x55afd3729ce0, 0xc0000d4020, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/github.com/docker/docker/client/ping.go:26 +0x167
github.com/docker/cli/cli/command.(*DockerCli).initializeFromClient(0xc0002620f0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/cli.go:346 +0x67
github.com/docker/cli/cli/command.(*DockerCli).Initialize(0xc0002620f0, 0xc0002551e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x55afd3373740, 0xc0003baf00)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cli/command/cli.go:255 +0x4a2
github.com/docker/cli/cli.(*TopLevelCommand).Initialize(0xc0000dbe40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cli/cobra.go:155 +0x7a
main.runDocker(0xc0002620f0, 0x55afd36d4820, 0xc0000d6010)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:257 +0xc1
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/cmd/docker/docker.go:292 +0xf3

goroutine 21 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x55afd1407b96)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:139 +0x9e
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23 +0x24
created by os/signal.init.0
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:29 +0x43

goroutine 23 [chan receive]:
github.com/docker/cli/vendor/k8s.io/klog.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x55afd4928ca0)
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/k8s.io/klog/klog.go:943 +0x8d
created by github.com/docker/cli/vendor/k8s.io/klog.init.0
    /go/src/github.com/docker/cli/vendor/k8s.io/klog/klog.go:403 +0x6e
```

I cound not find any answer through search and didn't find similar problem anywhere on the internet.

I thought maybe there is a problem with Go, so I installed go and ran a program with it successfully, but still no success with docker.

Comment: Apke sure you update Ubuntu with all the latest packages... uninstall docker and then do a frsh install

Comment: @SoumenMukherjeeI did that too, and updated the apt, updated all the installed packages, remove docker completely, updated apt again and installed docker. still the same error

Answer (score 2):

1. please check there is enough space in /var by df -h /var command
2. Check and make sure you are installed and running docker in root or admin access
3. Try delete the contents from /var/lib/docker and start the docker again
4. Also try getting logs by running systemctl status docker or serivce docker status
5. Check if any other service which blocks docker
6. check by disabling firewall and selinux getforce to be permissive
7. If you are using device mapper try clean that up and restart docker service
8. Check if there is any release notes on unbutu where there is known bug which blocks the system to start it

Get info on the system configuration and service/systemd stutus logs and post it to look for specific errors

I cant post all these checks in your comment itself since i am posting it in answer section , and this is not a answer rather suggesting you to check something

Update : 
Please try this link https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/665 and 
the command,no sure if the same command works for ubuntu, but give it a try

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

Comment: 1-3 or ok. for 4, I get  level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"

Comment: ok , it must be something i got few days back with fedora 31, there was workaround for it i havent tried , the new linux kernal does not support cgroup feature i think , Posted something on answer to check

Comment: thank you. although the command did not work, you gave me the idea to look after something. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering the same problem:

Thanks to @cslrns, I started searching about the error: `Your kernel does not support cgroup`

turns out in my ubuntu version, whose kernel is apparently not bionic, does not support something that the newer versions of docker-ce need.

do NOT install the docker-ce-cli, it's the problem. just install the latest docker-ce version without "bionic" in its name